# openGL error 0x0502 on Android when using Apportable and CCButton

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, apportable, spritebuilder

Specifically, the error reads `OpenGL error 0x0502 in -[CCES2Renderer resizeFromLayer:] 140`
This error only occurs on Android, not on the iOS version. I found the lines of code that cause this error (disabling them resolves the issue, but I need buttons in my game). These get called from `onEnter` from my main scene.

```
CCButton *newUserButton = [[CCButton alloc] initWithTitle:@"New user"];
[self addChild:newUserButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Apportable did you use?
If you using 1.1.04.1, then solution is simple, ‘apportable upgrade’.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/cocos2d-v3-with-apportable-problems/